# CKeditor stripping font tags instead of converting to span

Tags: ckeditor

I have a CKeditor instance (version 4.1.2) with font, size, text and background color buttons in its toolbar, all completely default.

It's created by replacing a `<textarea>` whose contents are loaded from a database.

When the loaded html contains  elements such as:

```
<h3><font color="red">Big Red Heading</font></h3>
```

CKeditor is simply stripping away the  tags, to leave:

```
<h3>Big Red Heading</h3>
```

Whereas, my expectations (according to the docs) were that it should convert this to:

```
<h3><span style="color:red">Big Red Heading</span></h3>
```

(It strips  tags with size and face attributes also, just the same way).

I haven't changed `allowedContent` or `colorButton_foreStyle`, or any other config setting that ought to have any effect on this issue.  I've tried removing all custom config (leaving an absolutely default instance of the editor), and it still happens.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening, and how to fix it?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**:  The default value of `colorButton_foreStyle` is set like this in the CKeditor source:

```
    CKEDITOR.config.colorButton_foreStyle = {
        element: 'span',
        styles: { 'color': '#(color)' },
        overrides: [ { element: 'font', attributes: { 'color': null } } ]
    };
```

...which is why I expected it would automatically convert font tags..?

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor hasn't got all possible transformations defined by default. There is a set of them and it will be enlarged in the future, but this specific one wasn't defined yet.

From [Advanced Content Filter guide - content transformations](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter-section-4):

> Currently, we have defined content transformations for only a handful of editor features, but their number will increase in future releases.

So, there are two solutions:

1. If you want to keep your `font` tags, then extend the Advanced Content Filter settings by defining [`config.extraAllowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) and change the `font` plugins settings like in [HTML output sample](http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.1.2/samples/plugins/htmlwriter/outputhtml.html).
2. If you want to automatically transform your `font` tags to their newer equivalents, then you can add a new transformations. Read more in [`filter#addTransformations`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-method-addTransformations) doc.

Comment: Thanks Reinmar.  I'll look into adding a filter transformation.  I already looked briefly at the doc reference, but right now none of it makes any sense to me... I don't suppose you could post an example of how to do it?  Also, if FONT tags aren't converted yet, I don't understand what the 'font' part is about in the definition of colorButton_foreStyle (see the edit at the end of my question).

Comment: The `overrides` part is for transformations, but done in different moment (while editing, not while loading data), by different module. This part was introduced earlier, before ACF and there's not automation yet, because actually it's not trivial :)

I'll try to write this transformation later.

Comment: Is this still valid? I saw that our CKEditor sometimes creates <font> and sometimes <span style="font-family">. We desperately need the latter.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. CKEditor will only create what it's configured to create. See e.g. http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-fontSize_style. Second thing is what happens with content pasted into CKEditor. That also can be controlled, either manually using the editor#paste event or using transformations (which I mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem in CKeditor 4. i searched but i didnt get solution. but i need it so i created my own method in js. its working great.

i created ownFunctoin:

function ConvertFontTagToSpanTag(str) {

```
        var startIndex = str.indexOf('<font');
        while (startIndex >= 0) {               

            var endIndex = str.substring(startIndex).indexOf('>');
            var subString1 = str.substring(startIndex, (startIndex + endIndex) + 1);
            var subString2 = subString1;              

            var mapObj = {
                size: "font-size:",
                face: "font-family:",
                color: "color:"
            };
            subString2 = subString2.replace(/size|face|color/gi, function (matched) {
                return mapObj[matched];
            });

            subString2 = subString2.replace(/['"]/g, ';');
            subString2 = subString2.replace(/=;/g, '');

            subString2 = subString2.replace('font', 'span');
            if (subString2.length > 6) {
                subString2 = [subString2.slice(0, 6), 'style=\"', subString2.slice(6)].join('');
                subString2 = [subString2.slice(0, subString2.length - 1), '\"', subString2.slice(subString2.length - 1)].join('');
            }

            //Converting Font-size           
            var sizeIndex = subString2.indexOf('font-size:');
            if (sizeIndex >= 0) {
                var sizeEndIndex = subString2.substring(sizeIndex).indexOf(';');
                var size = subString2.substring(sizeIndex + 10, (sizeIndex + sizeEndIndex));
                //Removing Font size
                subString2 = subString2.slice(0, (sizeIndex + sizeEndIndex) - 1) + subString2.slice((sizeIndex + sizeEndIndex));                  
                //Adding Font Size
                subString2 = [subString2.slice(0, (sizeIndex + sizeEndIndex)-1), ConvertSpanFontSize(size), subString2.slice((sizeIndex + sizeEndIndex)-1)].join('');

            }
            //end

            str = str.replace(subString1, subString2);

            startIndex = str.indexOf('<font');            

        }
        str = str.replace(/font>/g, 'span>');
        return str;

    }

    function ConvertSpanFontSize(size) {
        switch (size) {
            case '1': return '0.63em';
            case '2': return '0.82em';
            case '3': return '1.0em';
            case '4': return '1.13em';
            case '5': return '1.5em';
            case '6': return '2em';
            case '7': return '3em';                
            default: return '4em';
        }
```

Cheers...! Thank you