# <font> tag in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

When Im trying to read and html text generated by other wysiwyg text editor, CKEditor changes  tag for  getting something distint from the original. Does anybody know how to fix it?

This's what I have to show/save:

```
<h1>      Test <span style="background-color: #FFFF00"><s><strong>His </strong></s></span><strong>Parte       </strong>1    </h1>    <h1>      Clinical!!!!    </h1>    <h1>      siiiiiiiii    </h1>    <p>      &#160;    </p>    <p>      <span style="background-color: #00FFFF">MATIAS TELERAD</span>    </p>    <p>      <span style="background-color: #00FFFF">Linea nueva clicnical </span>    </p>    <p>      <span style="background-color: #00FFFF">Clinical 2 </span>    </p>    <p>      Clinical 3    </p>    <p>      La <span><font size="26px" color="#FF0000">concha </font></span>de la <span><font size="24px" color="#FFFF00">mona       </font></span>la puta que la <em><strong><span><u><font size="36px" color="#0000FF">pari&#243;</font></u></span></strong></em>.    </p>    <p>      <font color="#99ff99">cvqkjvneowvnoewnovnweonvonewovnioewniopvnew</font>    </p>
```

And this is the code read/save from CKEditor:

```
    <h1>Test <span style="background-color:#FFFF00"><s><strong>His </strong></s></span><strong>Parte </strong>1</h1>

<h1>Clinical!!!!</h1>

<h1>siiiiiiiii</h1>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span style="background-color:#00FFFF">MATIAS TELERAD</span></p>

<p><span style="background-color:#00FFFF">Linea nueva clicnical </span></p>

<p><span style="background-color:#00FFFF">Clinical 2 </span></p>

<p>Clinical 3</p>

<p>La concha de la mona la puta que la <em><strong><u>pari&oacute;</u></strong></em>.</p>

<p>cvqkjvneowvnoewnovnweonvonewovnioewniopvnew</p>
```

Thanks for your time and help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKeditor stripping font tags instead of converting to span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633948/ckeditor-stripping-font-tags-instead-of-converting-to-span)

Comment: Also to be noted that `<font>` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font). What WYSIWYG editor is the HTML coming from and what version of CKEditor are you using to load the text with?

Comment: CKEditor 4.3 @StevenV

Comment: I'll chek it @Houseman. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This doc shows how you can modify the formatting of the output, so you just have to specify the rules that you want:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/FCKeditor_HTML_Output